# How to create subdomain dynamically in PHP server in WHM

Tags: php

How to create subdomain dynamically in PHP? I have no any idea about to solve this problem. So, please give me proper solution or way to solve this problem.

Comment: Tell us what you did try. StackOverflow is designed for those who know what they want and roughly how to do it and just want to understand some more details. You seem not to be at this level yet. Google is your best friend now; ask here when you have something more concrete and when you can prove you have tried something.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for create subdomain in php
**

```
<?php
// cpanel user
$cPanelUser='user';
// cpanel password
$cPanelPass='pass';
// Will be used if not passed via parameter and not set in subdomains file
$rootDomain='domain.com';
$subDomain=subdomain';  
$newDoman=create_subdomain($subDomain,$cPanelUser,$cPanelPass,$rootDomain);

/////////////// END OF INITIAL SETTINGS ////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function create_subdomain($subDomain,$cPanelUser,$cPanelPass,$rootDomain) {
//  $buildRequest = "/frontend/x3/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=" . $rootDomain . "&domain=" . $subDomain;
    $buildRequest = "/frontend/paper_lantern/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=" . $rootDomain . "&domain=" . $subDomain . "&dir=public_html/" . $subDomain;
    $openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
    if(!$openSocket) {
        return "Socket error";
        exit();
    }
    $authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
    $authPass = base64_encode($authString);
    $buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
    $buildHeaders .= "\r\n";
    fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
    //while(!feof($openSocket)) {
    fgets($openSocket,128);
    //}
    fclose($openSocket);
    $newDomain = "http://" . $subDomain . "." . $rootDomain . "/";
    return $subDomain;
//  return "Created subdomain $newDomain";
}
?>
```

**

Comment: Hello Mr. Vijay,

I got a code from you and it's very useful. Thank you so much for your prompt response. 

However, I used this code and it has been created subdomain statically and I wanted to create DYNAMICALLY. So, can you please help me with new code which can be useful to create dynamic subdomain in PHP?

Thanks again.